# what is the word for person who always helps family but never helps friends?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know one guy who always helps his own family and relatives but he never ever helps his friends. How to call that person ?

Comment: *The Family Guy*? :D

Comment: Are you looking for a translation from a word for that in your own language, or are you just hoping there is a single word in any language (but specifically English) that captures that?

Comment: I think there may not be any word about `not helping friends`, question should have been `people who help only family, and no-one else`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Nepotism* is quite a specific word for this, but maybe is too strong for your needs. You could call the person a *nepotist*.

> **noun** 
> patronage bestowed or favoritism shown on the basis of family relationship, as in business and politics: *She was accused of nepotism
>   when she made her nephew an officer of the firm.*
>
> Origin:  1655–65;  <
>   Italian *nepotismo*.  See nephew, -ism

Dictionary.com, "[nepotism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nepotism)," in *[Dictionary.com Unabridged](http://dictionary.reference.com)*.  Random House, Inc. Accessed: July 09, 2014.

---

There is also the phrase *Blood is thicker than water* which means
 *family is more important than anyone else*. This is perhaps a softer term impressing the values of looking after the family over the needs of friends but doesn't provide a term that you can use to call someone directly.

> In modern society, the proverb "blood is thicker than water" is used
>   to imply that family ties (blood) are always more important (thicker)
>   than the ties you make among friends (water). It generally means that
>   the bonds of family and common ancestry are stronger than the bonds
>   between unrelated people (such as friendship).

Wikipedia contributors, "[Blood is thicker than water](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Blood_is_thicker_than_water&oldid=607379020)," *Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia*, (accessed July 9, 2014).

Answer (score 0):

"Nepotism" is good: I think you can say he is nepotistic because this is the adjective.

Comment: *Nepotism* and *nepotist* were listed 11 hours earlier in a previous answer.

Comment: Yes I am knowing this but I suggest adjective which other man did not. Thank you.